# EnvironmentObject doesn't update ContentView during login flow

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my `ContentView` with my `self.auth.isAuthenticated` variable:

```
@StateObject var auth = AuthViewModel()

// code not needed for question

 Group {
      if !self.auth.isAuthenticated {
           LandingView()
                .environmentObject(auth)

       } else {
           LoggedInView()
          }
       }
```

When I call this particular function, I try to update the `self.auth.isAuthenticated` variable from `false` to `true`

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var isAuthenticated = false


func verifyCode(phoneNumber: String, secret: String) {
        
        // code to verify

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.isAuthenticated = true // here is the issue

          }
     }

}
```

Here is the code where I call the function:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                             
TextField("Your secret code",text: $secret)
 
.onChange(of: secret) {
            if (secret.count >= 6 && secret.count <= 6) {
                                    print($0)
                                    authViewModel.verifyCode(phoneNumber: phoneNumber, secret: secret)
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

My `ContentView` doesn't receive the update.

Comment: Please show the code where you call `verifyCode`?

Comment: @burnsi Just updated

Comment: This is still not reproducible [mre]. Please add more code. E.g. how is `authViewModel` defined in your `LandingView`?

Comment: How you passing data to ContentView? from how I understand second view where call .onChange(of: secret)?